# How do you add the star ratings for products in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, rating, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store and I want to add star ratings to each of the products when you see their thumbnails. I already have the stars in the big product view but I want them to display below each thumbnail like in most ecommerce stores like timberland.com. I know i can use css to disable items from view but not add them. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can put this into your themes functions.php file:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'my_print_stars' );


function my_print_stars(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id = $wpdb->comments.comment_ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
    AND comment_post_ID = $post->ID
    AND comment_approved = '1'
    AND meta_value > 0
");

$rating = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id = $wpdb->comments.comment_ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
    AND comment_post_ID = $post->ID
    AND comment_approved = '1'
");

if ( $count > 0 ) {

    $average = number_format($rating / $count, 2);

    echo '<div class="starwrapper" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">';

    echo '<span class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__('Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce'), $average).'"><span style="width:'.($average*16).'px"><span itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</span> </span></span>';

    echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

Note that you may need to change `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` to a different hook depending on your design and where exactly you want the stars to show up.

This page lists **WooCommerce** action hooks: http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/extending/hooks/ .  I don't see any hooks associated with the thumbnail specifically, but you may try `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` or `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`.

(This function is essentially copied from WooCommerce's single-product-reviews.php)

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. Using sql directly in a plugin file is dangerous, and can lead to computability issues with future updates. Martyn's or ryanka's answer below should be the recommended answer.

Answer (score 19):

There's actually a much more terse way to handle this. Just use the built-in functions that Woocommerce has built out:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'get_star_rating' );
function get_star_rating()
{
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $average = $product->get_average_rating();

    echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
}
```

I've confirmed that this works for me.

Comment: Don't forget to check that the woocommerce plugin is enabled by wrapping the above code in an `if` condition: `if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

As of WooCommerce 3.0+ this is the correct code:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $id );
echo wc_get_rating_html( $product->get_average_rating() );
```

The get_rating_html() method on the product object has been deprecated.

More information here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_rating_html.html

Answer (score 1):

With those functions (or the shorter one below, which outputs the same HTML), you manage to output the rating in numbers, reusing Woocommerce's functions completely:

```
function get_star_rating() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    /*$average = $product->get_average_rating();*/
    echo $product->get_rating_html();
}
```

Then you need to style it to show the stars. For a rating of 3 out of 5 stars, Woothemes does it like this (the trick is in the width and :before of the corresponding CSS):

HTML (output by Woocommerce):

```
<div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" class="star-rating" title="Rated 3 out of 5">
    <span style="width:60%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue">3</strong> out of 5</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS (there may be some redundant lines in here):

```
#reviews .comment .star-rating {
    float: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 20px;
}
.star-rating {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    width: 5.1em;
    font-family: "fontawesome";
}

.star-rating:before {
    content: "\f006\f006\f006\f006\f006";
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    letter-spacing: 0\9;
    color: #fbfeff;
}

.star-rating span {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
}

.star-rating span:before {
    content: "\f005\f005\f005\f005\f005";
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    letter-spacing: 0\9;
    color: #f36557;
}

.star-rating {
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "fontawesome";
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, right after posting this I finally found this is done via CSS. Woothemes are great examples of how it's donde, in case anyone's wondering. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So maybe go ahead and post how you did it for the rest of us to see..??

Comment: Well, I did say how I did it. You just had to go and inspect any woocommerce theme by woothemes. I didn't put up the code because I don't know if that's really fair... but anyway, I've edited the answer with the code. I would go the original source still. Hope this clarifies it a bit though. Cheers!