# remove the single product review in woocommerce for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, wordpress-ecommerce

I have a wp site with woocommerce. We want to take out the 'your review' box but leave the stars.

I could just cut a chunk out of single-product-reviews.php (after moving it into my template of course) but I figure there's probably a way to unhook it?

How would I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the tab completely and add a seperate code whereever you would like the stars to be visible. Here is how you get only the stars:
[How do you add the star ratings for products in woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227121/how-do-you-add-the-star-ratings-for-products-in-woocommerce)