# How to show 0 star rating in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Woocommerce won't display any star rating if there are no ratings for a product. Is there a hook that I can use which will allow the star rating to be shown at all times even if it is 0?

Answer (score 0):

By Default woocommerce show the rating greater than 0
To show 0 rating too we need to remove the action that shows rating like

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
```

Then add custom function to show the rating

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'get_star_rating' );
function get_star_rating()
{
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $average = $product->get_average_rating();

    echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
}
```

Solution found in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/20794406/846060

Comment: FYI, a guide for WooCommerce element positions: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/