# How to display a message instead of star rating for products with no reviews

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am using a function based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20794406/4952851) to add the star rating to the product loop (unless it's the front page):

```php
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_star_rating' );
    function add_star_rating()
    {
        if(!is_front_page()){
            global $woocommerce, $product;
            $average = $product->get_average_rating();

            echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
        }
     }
```

If there are no reviews yet the page shows the 5 grey stars. How can I change it so that if there are no reviews for the product yet then it shows the text 'Be the first to review' or similar static text.

I can then also use this to add the 'Be the first to review' on the product page well, where no star rating is shown if there are no reviews. I can't find a way to count the reviews and check if zero.

I've also tried this but it doesn't seem to make a difference:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_star_rating' );
    function add_star_rating()
        {
            if(!is_front_page()){
                global $woocommerce, $product;
                $average = $product->get_average_rating();
                $count = $product->get_rating_counts();
                if ($count > 0){
                    echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<div>No reviews yet</div>';
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: `get_average_rating` probably just gets you an “average” of `0` for these products, I suppose. Use `get_rating_counts` to check if there actually where any reviews for the product, and then base your output on that.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks - I just tried that and I've updated the question, thanks

Comment: The code of the `WC_Product` class has this property defined as an array, `'rating_counts'      => array(),` - so check what gets actually returned by this method, it does not appear to be a mere number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice as an extra check

```php
function add_star_rating() {
    // Check if reviews ratings are enabled - WooCommerce Settings
    if ( ! wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( !is_front_page() ) {
        global $product;

        // Get average
        $average = $product->get_average_rating();

        // Average > 0
        if ($average > 0) {
            echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div>No reviews yet</div>';
        }   
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_star_rating', 10 );
```